# SATA to USB Hard Drive Not Being Detected

Tags: windows, data-recovery, sata, macbook

So my old desktop computer crashed and I removed the hard drive and bought a SATA to USB adapter cable to plug into my MacBook to get the data off of my hard drive.

But I am on my second cable and it still is not being detected? What could be the issue? I even tried to connect it to a Windows PC but it was still not detected.

Image of cable:

[image: Image of cable]

Image of hard drive:
[image: Image of hard drive]

Comment: Maybe the hard drive is dead?

Comment: Have you tested the adapter with an other drive? Is it a HDD or a SDD? In case of a HDD: Can you hear it spinning up? Observe ```dmesg -w``` while plugging in the USB adapter into the MacBook. You will likely get some errors.

Comment: “My old desktop computer crashed...” Who’s to say it wasn’t the hard drive that caused it? It would be one of the most likely things to fail.

Comment: Hmm desktop. A 3.5" hard drive?

Comment: I have 2 of them and both failed

Answer (score 1):

#### You're using the wrong adapter for a 3.5" HDD

Basic USB-to-SATA adapters that obtain all of their power from a USB port and not from a separate power supply are only designed to power 2.5" HDD, not 3.5" HDD models.

This screenshot confirms that your adapter, as well as another popular budget model, both officially only support 2.5" HDD drives:

[image]

This is what you should be using for a 3.5" HDD:

[image]

It's certainly possible that the hard drive suffered a catastrophic failure but you won't know for sure until you first attempt to access it using an adapter that's capable of spinning up such a heavy mechanical drive.

I have tried various model adapters and have found [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MYU0EAU) to be by far the most reliable one.

Comment: I have a SATA HD 2.5" removed from a malfunctioning laptop computer.  I bought a similar adpater, but mine has a DC jack for an optional 5V @ 2A power supply to drive 3.5" HDDs.  My Windows 10 computer recognizes the drive, but my Windows 11 system doesn't (gives USB device not recognized).  What could it be?